# Can a risk-averse agent's Certainty Equivalent be lower than the lowest possible outcome of a gamble?

Tags: risk-aversion

Suppose there is an agent who faces the following gamble g:

- 50\$ with probability 1/3
- 100\$ with probability 1/3
- 150\$ with probability 1/3

Clearly, the E[g] = 100\$. Since agent is risk averse, we would expect that U(E[g]) < U(CE) , where CE is the certainty equivalent. Now, my question is, is it hypothetically possible that the agent's Certainty Equivalent of this gamble will be below 50\$, or is it necessarily true that it will be somewhere between 50\$ and 100\$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"Since agent is risk averse, we would expect that $U(E[g]) < U(CE)$ ,
>   where $CE$ is the certainty equivalent."*

This is wrong. I presume the Expected Utility Property holds here, so, if we denote the gamble by $G$, a discrete uniform random variable taking three values according to the setup, we have

$$U(CE) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^3p_iU(g_i) = E[U(G)] < U[E(G)]$$

the inequality to the right due to Jensen's Inequality and the assumption that $U()$ is concave. This also gives us

$$ CE < E(G)$$

which should be intuitive: a risk-neutral person would demand $E(G)$, the expected value of the gamble, in order not to take it. A risk-averse person would require *less*, to leave the gamble.

Having cleared this, the OP asks: **Is it possible that $CE < \min G$?**

The answer is : **No.** Assume that the gamble outcomes are ordered, so $\min G = g_1$.

**Ad absurdum**, assume that $CE < g_1$ holds. Then we will have

$$U(CE) < U(g_1)$$

Using the definition of $CE$ we replace the left-hand side

$$\sum_{i=1}^3p_iU(g_i) < U(g_1) \implies p_2U(g_2) + p_3U(g_3) < (1-p_1) U(g_1)$$

$$\implies p_2U(g_2) + p_3U(g_3) < p_2U(g_1) + p_3U(g_1)$$

$$\implies p_2[U(g_2)-U(g_1)] + p_3[U(g_3)-U(g_1)] < 0$$

But this is impossible since $g_1 = \min\{g_1,g_2, g_3\}$ and so

$U(g_2)-U(g_1) >0$ and $U(g_3)-U(g_1) >0$.

So assuming $U(CE) < U(g_1)$ led us to an impossible situation, and therefore  it cannot hold.

Intuitively, the *worst* outcome of being in the gamble is to receive the minimum payoff -so for a rational agent, even if it is risk-averse, it would be irrational to accept less than the worst outcome, since then it would *certainly* do worse than being in the gamble. Note that "aversion to risk" does *not* mean "take away *all* risk at *all* costs".

Answer (score 2):

The lottery you show is equivalent to having two lotteries, one where you get \$50 with certainty and one with the following payoffs:

- \$0 with probability 1/3
- \$50 with probability 1/3
- \$100 with probability 1/3

The first lottery has a certainty equivalent of \$50. The second lottery has no negative payoffs and so shouldn't ever have a negative price. Therefore the certainty equivalent must be $\geq 50$.